# Makefile example for c4droid

Tags: c++, makefile

Anybody have any makefile for c4droid using c++ compiler and libraries like "cstudio"?

The app not have examples this type.

I have received error message about this library, but not show when i have compiled without Makefile.

I have much problems when try compiling.

Receive messages type "multiple declarations for main" when have only main declaration and using parameters "int argc, char * argsv[])"

Other message is "Id returned 1 exit status", but my main methos is int and return 0. When i changed to return 1, the message is the same.

this is my makefile:

```
GCC= $(CXX) 
CFLAGS= -c -Wall -lm -v -ldl -lz 
LDFLAGS=src (c4droid:CURSRCDIR)
SOURCES=main.c 
SOURCES+=src/Classe1.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o) $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE=ProjetoTeste

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
$(GCC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
$(GCC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

I like to see others that work, for compare and, maibe, find the problem.

Also would be interesting to other people who actually use or would like to use this app for development.

Comment: `ld returned 1 exit status` is not telling you that your main returned `1` it is telling you that the `ld` command returned that which means you had some sort of linking failure.

Comment: Your `SOURCES` variable is going to have both `main.c` and `main.o` in it. Because the `.cpp` substitution expansion will leave it as `main.c` in the output and the `.c` substitution expansion will make it `main.o` in the output. You probably want to wrap that whole left-hand side in a `$(filter %.o,...)` call.

Comment: As far as the linking problem you are going to need to show us the command that make ran and the output.